# Concerning the proof pf the Eisenstein's Criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm stuck with the following part of an exercise that asks to proof Eisenstein's Criterion:

Let $P$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the form $ P = a_nX^n + a_{n-1}X^{n-1} + .... + \ a_0 $ such that $ p \nmid a_n$, $p \mid a_j \ (\forall i \in {0,...,n-1})$ and $p^2 \nmid a_0$.
Now suppose that there are two polynomials $Q$ and $R$ such that $P = Q * R$ and neither $Q$ nor $R$ are euqal to $\pm 1$. Show that both $Q$ and $R$ are of degree bigger or euqal to $1$.

I attempted the following:

W.l.o.g. we suppose that $Q$ is a constant polynomial meaning $R = c_0$. We further set $Q$ to $ Q = b_nX^n + b_{n-1}X^{n-1} + .... + \ b_0 $. Therefore we got:

$ P = c_0b_nX^n + c_0b_{n-1}X^{n-1} + .... + \ c_0b_0 $

Since $ p \nmid a_n$ we know that $ p \nmid c_0$ and $p \nmid b_n$. And since for all $i$ holds $a_i = c_0*b_i$ it follows from $p \mid a_j \ (\forall j \in {0,...,n-1})$ that $ p \mid b_j \ (\forall j \in {0,...,n-1})$.

But I don't know how to continue from here. Could you give me any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you call Eisenstein's Criterion is not really that. The following **is**: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/16.pdf Observe the polynomial is in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$, but at the end, if the conditions are satisfied, we'll get **irreducubility* both in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ and in $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ (you could also use Gauss Lemma for this last piece)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is obviously false. Just take $Q(x)=P(x)$ and $R(x)=1$.

Comment: Sorry I fortgot to write that neither $Q$ nor $R$ are equal to $\pm 1$.

Comment: @3nondatur Then perhaps you should focus on the actual Eisenstein Criterion and what it really says instead of trying to prove things that might take your attention away from the actual point of this important criterion ...

Comment: @3nondatur All right. Then take $Q(x)=\frac12P(x)$ and $R(x)=2$.